# How to resolve Powershell start cmd path error?

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd, path

When I use the following command on the powershell console, it works correctly and I see admin command prompt open and the script `sudo.bat` executes correctly.

`sudo.bat` contains one line, `cd c:\temp\`

```
Start-Process cmd \"/k C:\Users\Varun\Documents\sudo.bat cd /d %cd%\" -Verb RunAs
```

[image]

But below one doesn't work, i.e. when the path has space, the admin command prompt opens but it doesn't run the script file.

```
Start-Process cmd \"/k C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat cd /d %cd%\" -Verb RunAs
```

[image]

I tried following and it did not work:

```
Start-Process cmd \"/k \"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat\" cd /d %cd%\" -Verb RunAs
```

and:

```
Start-Process cmd \"/k 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat' cd /d %cd%\" -Verb RunAs
```

Comment: What is the thought process behind changing the current directory to the current directory?

Comment: Let's say i am at a path c:\temp and it is not admin. I want to have a script that will contain the above line and so i will run that script (env variable), and it will open a Visual Studio Admin command prompt at the same path. I am able to achieve the above without VS command prompt already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use extra quotes. Like so:

```
Start-Process cmd \"/k ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat"" cd /d %cd%\" -Verb RunAs
```

Comment: one more thing. This changes the current directory to Visual Studio one. Do you think it is possible to return to same location where we wrote the command?

Comment: I belive you could declare variable for current path and then use it to change your location.

Comment: @VVV: I usually use `Push-Location $PSScriptRoot` or `Push-Location .` at first to "temporarily save" the location and `Pop-Location` at the end of the script :D